# Detect playing card number python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to create a play card number detector unfortunately without sucess.

I have created a folder with pictures of numbers. With the raspberry pi camera i take a picture of a card and i cut out the number. Then i compare the cutted number with the numberpictures in the folder.

Unfortunaly, the whole thing does not work reliably. What am I doing wrong ? 
Are there other ways ?

The code:

```
def detectCard(self):
        listindex = 0
        cardplace = 1000
        similarity = 0

        while (listindex <= 8):
            # Load image and template
            image = cv2.imread("/home/pi/Desktop/Pythonprojekte/tmp/pycharm_project_712/Cards/picture.png")
            template = cv2.imread(self.cardlink[listindex])


            # Convert to grayscale for faster detection
            imageGray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            templateGray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


            imageGray = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(imageGray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 115, 1)
            templateGray = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(templateGray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 115, 1)


            cv2.imwrite("/home/pi/Desktop/Pythonprojekte/tmp/pycharm_project_712/Cards/imageGray.png", imageGray)
            cv2.imwrite("/home/pi/Desktop/Pythonprojekte/tmp/pycharm_project_712/Cards/templateGray.png", templateGray)

            # Analysis
            result = cv2.matchTemplate(imageGray, templateGray, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
            min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
            print("Value at Index ", listindex,"=",max_val)

            if (max_val > similarity):
                cardplace = listindex
                similarity = max_val
                #print("Similarity =", similarity)

            listindex = listindex + 1

            if (listindex == 9):
                print("The Card is in the Index", cardplace)
                print (similarity)
```

Comment: template matching is usually problematic when you have rotations, illumination changes, scale changes, occlusion, and maybe some more that does not come to my mind now. It is better that you post some sample images as well to get an idea what is happening and what can be wrong... in most cases, it would be good if you warp the card such that it matches the template card size and rotation and then cut the numbers. Also, other techniques related to machine learning may help you in this task

Comment: Another way which is more difficult is to use [image moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment). If I remember correctly, some of them are invariant to rotation and scaling.

Comment: @Joe that is true as well, and also OpenCV already has it implemented in [matchShapes](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#matchshapes) function.